# Logging in linux server with ssh keys

Tags: linux, ssh, key, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have two servers `A` and `B`.

Is it possible to do password less logins to `B` without chnaging anything on `B`.

I mean i want to configure `A` with whatever setting so that i can login to `B` like copying private/public keys etc.

Currently i am adding `A` public key to `B` 's `authorized_keys`.

Is there any other way of doing without editing file on `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently i am adding A public key to B 's authorized_keys

This is problematic because anyone - friend of foe - who has access to A's private key, implicitly has access to B.

What I suggest involves a simple setup **with a single key pair**

- You have your own key pair
- You copy your public key - and only that - to every server you want to access
- On your box you add this to `.ssh/config`:

  ```
  Host A
    ForwardAgent yes
  ```
- You run `ssh-add`

At this point you can connect to A. Big woop, so what ? Well, if from A you connect to B, it will just work. This is very secure and there is a single key you have to worry about: your own.

Read more about [SSH agent forwarding at github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

On A & B you firstly must already have generated your pubkeys with (assume you already have):

```
sudo ssh-keygen
```

Then use the command from machine A:

```
ssh-copy-id user@machineB -p <port #>
```

If you have generated a password for host B's private key you will have to enter that once and machine A's id_pub.rsa contents will be copied into machine B's authorized_keys.